# How to replace Nexus 5 battery?

Tags: battery, battery-life, nexus-5

As we all know, the battery in the Nexus 5 is sealed inside the phone chassis and cannot be replaced by the owner the way other phones' batteries can be. I am not particularly in favor of disassembling the phone by myself and manually replacing the battery. The point is, say I use this device for a few years: sooner or later it will need a new battery as the old one wears out. So how do I replace it ? Is there a safe, convenient way to get this done without taking any risks with the device ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a free guide available on ifixit.com:

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nexus+5+Battery+Replacement/26009

Of course, when disassembling the phone you always take various risks of damaging it, but I assume you are aware of that.